# Firebase recyclerview shows no values in release mode but it works perfectly in debug mode

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm not able to display firebase recyclerview in released mode, but it shows all the values in debug mode. This issue is happening after i met firebase database limit. I have now upgraded plan from flame to blaze. But, the issue is still not resolved.

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("quizTimings");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<CarouselModel> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<CarouselModel>()
                    .setQuery(query, CarouselModel.class)
                    .build();

    scrollView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.picker);

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CarouselModel, TimeViewHolder>(options) {

        @Override
        public TimeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_time, viewGroup, false);

            return new TimeViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(TimeViewHolder timeViewHolder, int i, final CarouselModel carouselModel) {

            try {
                String quizTimings = carouselModel.getTime();
                String timeMoney = carouselModel.getTimeMoney();
                timeViewHolder.timeShow.setText(quizTimings);
                timeViewHolder.timeMoney.setText(timeMoney);
                Log.w("timeMoney",timeMoney);
                /*final Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.bounce);
                MyBounceInterpolator interpolator = new MyBounceInterpolator(0.2, 20);
                myAnim.setInterpolator(interpolator);
                startBtn.startAnimation(myAnim);*/
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                String err = (ex.getMessage()==null)?"SD Card failed":ex.getMessage();
                Log.e("sdcard-err2:",err);
            }
        }
    };
    //For setting time
    /*CarouselModel carouselModel = new CarouselModel("ewt","wtt","ete","wte");
    quizTiming.push().setValue(carouselModel);*/

    CustomLinearLayout linearLayoutManager = new CustomLinearLayout(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);

    scrollView.addItemDecoration(new LinePagerIndicatorDecoration(MainActivity.this));
    scrollView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    scrollView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow all the steps specified in the guide:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

. If need be, create a new OAuth Client, new configuration file (the google-services.json) file and do everything step-by-step.

Also try adding a Web Client giving the same credentials. And for Android as well as Web client give both the SHA1 for debug as well as the release keystores. In Android Studio, at extreme left you will see a tab saying "Build Variants". Select the release mode there and do everything after that.

Comment: I had tried changing build variant to release mode and then debugging the app inorder to find out the error. But, debug as well as release variant works perfectly and displays recyclerview. But, when i'm generating a signed release apk and installing that apk into my phone. Then, again it does not display any firebase recyclerview and app crashes with nullpointer exception even though there is data inside the recyclerview.

Comment: Please make sure you give both the SHA1 for debug as well as the release keystores in firebase project, then generate google-json file and add it in the your project, did you follow these steps.